# How can i prove a closed ball is the closure of a open ball?

Tags: vector-spaces

do I stick to definitions or theres a helpful theorem arround?
Let $W:=\{y\in X : ||y-x||\leq r\}$ and $S:=\{y\in X : ||y-x||<r\}$ for any $r>0$.

If $z\in W$ and $z_n:=(r-1/n)z$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $\lim z_n=z$ and then $\overline{S}=W$.

This is suposed to be a hint, but how?

Comment: The statement is not true in general metric spaces, so you may want to mention your spaces of interest ...

Comment: It said vector spaces and normed spaces a second ago, i think that's what she asks

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of closure, you just need to show that any $z \in W$ is the limit of a sequence of points $z_1,z_2,\ldots$ of $S$. The hint gives you exactly this.